# Best Clear case plug-in for VS 2008 in Win 7 (64 bit) machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, clearcase

I need Clear case plug-in for VS 2008 on Win7 64 bit machine. Can anyone suggest a good option?

-

Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ClearCase plugin for Visual Studio is included with current ClearCase 7.1.x.

**But** you need to have Visual Studio installed first, and then install ClearCase.
That way, ClearCase Installation Manager will detect the Visual Studio (2005, 2008 or 2010) and will add the ClearCase plugin.

Comment: I am using 7.1.1 version on Clearcase, however plug-in was not installed. Can it be installed seperately?

Comment: @Ram: no, you need to uninstall ClearCase and then reinstall it: the plugin will be proposed then.

Comment: Can he use IBM Installation Manager to add in the plugin?

Comment: @kolslorr: nope, I tried numerous time, but the Installation Manager will not propose the plugin when you try to "modify" the ClearCase installed.